# limit bandwidth and space usage of each Virtual Host?

Tags: nginx, debian, virtualhost

I am starting a small web hosting company to teach me about system administration and one of the problems I am having is how would I limit the bandwidth and disk space of each virtual host (Debain/nginx)? Or am I going about it the wrong way and should not use virtual hosts?

Comment: I absolutally agree that doing it is the best way to learn, and I applaud your initative. However a web hosting company generally has someone who already knows what they're doing, because you don't want to lose everyone's data by accident because you're still learning - even if they haven't paid you any money for it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I posted it on server fault, and it is not really serious, it will be a free web host with small limits.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [mod_bandwidth](http://www.cohprog.com/mod_bandwidth.html) to restrict bandwidth. It can be used per directory, per file, etc... so, you just have to configure it per VirtualHost.

For the Disk Space, just use the quota. Create a unix account per customer, and assign them the quota. That should be quite well documented in the web.

Comment: But throttling bandwidth pushes load back onto the server - so you could end up with a DOS

Answer (score 1):

Some quick Googling shows me that you could use a Squid proxy to set queues for data called 'data pools'.
You can apparently also use IPROUTE2 and TC (can't post link, I'm not awesome enough)

From http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Bandwidth-Limiting-HOWTO.html#AEN65

> Apart from normal caching, Squid has a special feature called delay pools. Thanks to delay pools, it is possible to limit internet traffic in a reasonable way, depending on so-called 'magic words', existing in any given URL. For example, a magic word could be '.mp3', '.exe' or '.avi', etc. Any distinct part of a URL (such as .avi) can be defined as a magic word.

Also see an article on serverwatch.com titled Reining-in-Bandwidth-With-Squid-Proxying

Squid is probably the simplest way, and you can do a lot of other cool things with it, too.

Answer (score 0):

Its not simple. I suspect that it won't be possible simply using vhosts to enforce limits unless you put a scripted proxy in front of the webserver (and that only addresses the bandwidth problem, unless you restrict file uploads to a scripted web interface).

But surely it makes more sense from a business point of view to sell a package which includes X bandwidth and Y disk usage then bill the customer for excesses (which you can measure easily from the disk footprint and the access logs).

C.

Comment: That doesn't work if the customer degrades service to other customers. Even if you bill for overages, you still usually need a limit. (Plus, your $50/year customer may balk at the $1,000 bill if they host a video that goes viral. So you usually still need a limit.)

Answer (score 0):

To limit total bandwidth usage refer to the KikoV answer, I'm discussing about limiting disk space.

In fact there's no straight way to limit disk space, but you have two options:

1. You can schedule a script which
   calculates used disk space for
   example every day and bans/alerts
   exceeded clients.
2. You can create a
   system user for each of your clients
   and use the file system quota
   manager. Read [this article](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-journaled-quota-on-debian-lenny) for
   more information.